# Compost in the sun or shade?

Tags: composting

Is it better to have my compost pile in the sun, or in the shade? I have space on the north and south walls of my house, and want to know which would be a wiser place for the pile.

Comment: Questions of this type are typical at [Gardening.SE.](http://gardening.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends a lot on your climate and what you're putting in your compost.

Compost likes to be warm, so sun helps.

Compost likes to be moist - like a wrung-out sponge. If the sun would cause it to over-dry in the summer, or the shade would allow it to become over-wet in the winter, then you'll need to adjust accordingly.

You can add water to a compost pile, but using fresh drinking water that way seems counter to the very purpose of composting. Greywater is a good choice, and it includes some additional nutrients.

If your compost is too wet, you can dry it out by mixing in some dry sawdust. I don't recommend wood shavings, however, because they break down very slowly. (It's unfortunate, because wood shavings are an abundant waste product.)

Comment: At least you can use wood shavings for mulch. I put twigs, branches, and small solid wood carpentry waste through a wood chipper and spread it around the hedge at the back of the house.